# No appropriate default constructor available?

Tags: class, constructor, c++-cli

I've got a peculiar error writing some C++/CLI code. I'm trying to make a copy of a class which holds some data.

The class is defined as:

```
public ref class RawDataPacket
{
protected:
    float* m_internalData;

public:
    RawDataPacket(const float* newInternalData);
    RawDataPacket(const RawDataPacket^ rdp);
    RawDataPacket(RawDataPacket^ rdp);
    RawDataPacket();
};
```

When I try and make use of the class as follows:

```
void SomeClass::SomeFunction( RawDataPacket^ rdp )
{
    // Send a copy of the packet to anyone interested.
    RawDataPacket^ rdp1 = gcnew RawDataPacket( rdp );
    ForwardData( rdp1 );
}
```

I get:

```
error C2512: 'RawDataPacket' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

I thought that `RawDataPacket();` had that covered? ..or am I missing something really obvious there?

**[Edit]** The body of `RawDataPacket()` looks like this:

```
RawDataPacket::RawDataPacket()
{
    m_internalData = nullptr;
}
```

**[Edit2]** The full compiler output looks like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MySoftware, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>RawDataPacket.cpp
1>Controller.cpp
1>.\Controller.cpp(452) : error C2512: 'MySoftware::RawDataPacket' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Projects\Experiments\MySoftware\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>MySoftware - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: does the body of RawDataPacket() exit?

Comment: It looks to me as though that should be an "appropriate default contstructor" as well... However, that isn't the constructor you are using at the time.  When you do a Step-Into, does it go into one of your contstructors and then throw that error? or does it just throw that error on the line in the SomeClass::SomeFunction function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! It occurred to me that I'd forward-declared the RawDataPacket class in the header of the Controller class.

I tried including the header in there and removing the forward declaration and it worked. So it turns out that despite forward-declaring the class I'd forgotten to include the header in Controller.cpp

That could have been a nasty one to find.. cheers for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

use explicit before the constructor if you are having parameters for constructor.